# Eclipse Source / Organize Imports option does not show up for project or folder

Tags: java, eclipse, code-organization

I am using Eclipse (Version: Kepler Service Release 1). When I have a file open, I can right-click, select Source, and select **Organize Imports**. However, when I click the project or a folder within the project, this option does not show up. The only option that shows up on the Source menu is **Format**. Ctrl-Shift-O also does not work.

My project is in the buildpath and the project compiles. And, another developer on my team with the same configuration sees the same behavior.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Is the project a Java project (does it have the Java nature)? The Format only Source menu appears for non-Java projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Package Explorer for that. If it is not visible, open it from `Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer`. 
Then you can either perform `Ctrl+Shift+O` on the project, or via `right click -> Source -> Organize Imports`. You can do this on packages, as well.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I was right-clicking in the _Project_ Explorer. The Source sub-menu is only properly populated in the _Package_ Explorer. Thank you both so much!

The odd thing is that in the Java EE perspective the default is the Project Explorer, whereas in the plain Java perspective the Package Explorer is the default. That's what tripped me up. Eclipse is taking some getting used to . . .